# VBScript - using IF statements in a mail script?

Tags: vbscript, if-statement

I really need some quick tips here.

I've got this [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) script which sends an e-mail. And I want to do several checks to see if an attribute is true and if it is, write an additional line in the mail.

How can I do this? This is part of the script:

```
    obMessage.HTMLBody = ""_
        & "<MENU>"_
        & "<LI type = square>This is a line</i>."_
```

I want something which looks like this:

```
    obMessage.HTMLBody = ""_
        & "<MENU>"_
    If statement1 = true Then
        & "<LI type = square>This is an additional line</i>."_
    end if
```

Preferrably, could some select statements be made? I don't really mind what the code looks like, I just want it to work as soon as possible :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will look like spaghetti code no matter how you do it. This is one of the most straight forward approach:

```
obMessage.HTMLBody = & "<MENU>"

if statement1 then
  obMessage.HTMLBody = obMessage.HTMLBody & "<LI type=""square"">This is a line</LI>."
end if

if statement2 then
  obMessage.HTMLBody = obMessage.HTMLBody & "<LI type=""square"">This is another line</LI>."
end if
```

However, I suggest that you concatenate the lines to a temporary string, the assign the resulting string to obMessage.HTMLBody, such as:

```
Dim Foo
Foo = "<MENU>"

if statement1 then
  Foo = Foo & "<LI type=""square"">This is a line</LI>."
end if

.
.
.

obMessage.HTMLBody = Foo
```

Comment: Ah ok. So this is actually what I was wondering. Because I cannot do an IF statement inside a string, obviously. So I had to do this outside. Thanx! :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
obMessage.HTMLBody = "Begin Text" & _ 
IIf(statement1 = true, "<LI type = square>This is an additional line</i>.", "") & _
"Further text"
```

Should work ok.

Comment: It won't work because you are missing the string concatenation operator. Also, VBScript doesn't have the built-in `IIf` function.